# purchase item in Store using In App purchase

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am simply trying to implement in app purchase on my Demo Programm.I am Doing Following Code.

```
  Guid product1TempTransactionId;
   async void BuyFirstProduct()
   {
       if (!LicenceInfo.ProductLicenses["test_coins10"].IsActive)
       {
           try
           {
               await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("test_coins10",false);

               PurchaseResults purchaseResults = await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("test_coins10");


               switch (purchaseResults.Status)
               {
                   case ProductPurchaseStatus.Succeeded:
                       product1TempTransactionId = purchaseResults.TransactionId;
                       Debug.WriteLine("Sucess" + product1TempTransactionId.ToString());
                       // Grant the user their purchase here, and then pass the product ID and transaction ID to currentAppSimulator.reportConsumableFulfillment
                       // To indicate local fulfillment to the Windows Store.
                       break;

                   case ProductPurchaseStatus.NotFulfilled:
                       //product1TempTransactionId = purchaseResults.TransactionId;
                       Debug.WriteLine("Fail");
                       break;
                   case ProductPurchaseStatus.NotPurchased:
                       Debug.WriteLine("Not Purchase");
                       break;
               }


           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               msg.Content = "" + e.ToString();
               msg.Title = "Error";
                 msg.ShowAsync();

           }

       }
       else
       {
           msg.Content = "You Already Have a This Pack";
           msg.Title = "Error";
           await msg.ShowAsync();
       }
   }
```

Here test_coins10 is my Product id Which is register in App Store.Here in this Code I am getting Following Error

The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000B)

While I am just write Following Code

```
        await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("test_coins10");
```

its work perfect but Compiler Always going on not purchase block.

Please Note that Product test_coins10 is Consumable

Please reply if any one have any Different idea.

Answer (score 0):

Reference :- [**Enable consumable in-app product purchases**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn532255.aspx)

**Why Exception ?**

You are getting The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range `(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000B)` this exception because :-

```
 await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("test_coins10",false);
```

this method is deprecated in new release. hence your exception. So use :-

```
CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("test_coins10");
```

**Why NotPurchaseBlock ?**

You are always going to NotPurchaseBLock Because you are not `reporting back to Store` about the fulfillment of consumable product.
This can be achieved by :-

```
FulfillmentResult result = await CurrentAppSimulator.ReportConsumableFulfillmentAsync("product2", product2TempTransactionId);
```

**Edit :-** 'There is a problem completing your requist.try again later.Inquiring minds may find this error code helpful:805a0194'

This can occur because of multiple reasons:- so google it there are lots of results already there..

**But for this Error Code :- 805a0194 :-**

1. Problem :- This error occurs when there is a temporary service
   disruption.
2. Solution :- Wait a little while and then try again.
3. [Cross check your region](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/4112/error-code-805a0194-when-submitting-an-app-review)

hope it'll help :)

Comment: Is there any solution..??

Comment: but how can i send fulfillment because fulfillment required transactionId But purchase is not Properly done so how can Pass the Transaction id.Transaction Id value is 0000-000-00000.

Comment: And I am Beginner so it's Might be Having Some Error.as per my knowledge transaction Id is only getting if and only if Purchase is properly Done.

Comment: @ChiragSolanki If purchase is not properly done then in that case you can't do anything, First make that correct first. Also remove the "await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("test_coins10",false);" for your code.. and try. When you go to this switch case "case ProductPurchaseStatus.Succeeded:" then check the comment in your code itself. There are some information how you will do the fullfillment..

Comment: I am sorry Bro it's having Same Error.Compiler in Not Going in Success Block.Did you have any idea Why purchase is not Succeeded.?? and Thanx For REPLY

Comment: @ChiragSolanki I have to simulate the problem for the exact solution.. Right now I'm not getting why it is not working, I'll come back to you after the simulation, but right now it is not possible, i'll check it out asap..

Comment: it's ok.And Thak you so much.

Comment: Hello In My Code I am just write CurrentApp instead of CurrentAppSimulater than App i going Fine but Compiler throws Following Error While try to Download product in App Store.

Comment: i Already visit this link.I also try to change my Region but Error Remain Same.I am working on this if i get Solution than I post on the Comment.

Comment: Any more news on this?